# php session handler retrieve in another script

Tags: php, session, cookies

Hi I am trying to use the session handler here :
https://gist.github.com/eddmann/10262795
So in test1.php I have the following code - which works fine:

```
<?php
include'SecureSessionHandler.php';
$session=new SecureSessionHandler('sess');
ini_set('session.save_handler', 'files');
session_set_save_handler($session, true);
$set_path = __DIR__.'/sessions';
if(!file_exists($set_path)){die('PATH : '.$set_path.' NOT THERE !!!');   }
if(!is_writable($set_path)){die('PATH : '.$set_path.' NOT WRITABLE!!!'); }
session_save_path( $set_path );
$session->start();
if ( ! $session->isValid(5)) {
    $session->destroy();
}
// SET SESSIONS
$session->put('hello.world', 'bonjour');
$session->put("user",  "8");
$session->put("admin", "1");
$session->put("panel", "0");
//
echo '<br />';
echo 'SESSION VALUES:';
echo '<br />';
echo $session->get('panel').'<br />';
echo $session->get('admin').'<br />';
echo $session->get('user').'<br />';
echo $session->get('hello.world').'<br />';
```

So then in another script test2.php I am trying to retrieve some values set in test1 but I get nothing -- any ideas:

```
<?php
include'SecureSessionHandler.php';
$session=new SecureSessionHandler('sess');
$session->start();
echo 'SESSION VALUES:';
echo $session->get('panel').'<br />';
echo $session->get('admin').'<br />';
echo $session->get('user').'<br />';
echo $session->get('hello.world').'<br />';
```

Comment: you are creating new session `$session=new SecureSessionHandler('sess');` so it will override old session.

Comment: comment that line out and you get: Undefined variable: _SESSION in /opt/lampp/htdocs/php_test/SecureSessionHandler.php on line 165

Comment: Yes, because there is not session object. You should define this in a parent class or we can say in main class then inherit that class in your class.

Comment: ok cheers I'll give it a go...

Comment: cool, best of luck..